# How to reload a component without refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-component

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've built out a simple quote generator project in React and would like the new quote to load without rendering the entire page. Currently, im using hooks and the quotes state resides in one component is it possible to reload/refresh state from another component using a click handler?

Project link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-generator-czffn?file=/src/components/buttons/Buttons.js

How it's currently reloading, using a refreshPage function.
Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';

const Buttons = ({ quotes, getNewQuote }) => {
  const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quotes.joke}`;
  //   console.log(twitterUrl);

  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className='button-container'>
      <button
        onClick={() => window.open(twitterUrl, '_blank')}
        className='twitter-button'
        id='twitter'
        tittle='Tweet This!'
      >
        <i className='fab fa-twitter'></i>
      </button>
      <button id='new-quote' onClick={refreshPage}>
        New Quote
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: Updated my answer to include an example if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the quote is to show a new quote without refreshing the entire page, remove the axios request from the hook and put it in its own function.

```
  const getQuotes = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        setQuotes(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

// ...

<Buttons onClick={getQuotes} quotes={quotes} />
```

Then adjust the button to get use this function when it's clicked:

```
const Buttons = ({ quotes, getNewQuote, onClick }) => {

// ...

<button id="new-quote" onClick={onClick}>
  New Quote
</button>
```

You might want to add an animation while it's retrieving things as well with a `useState` for loading, but this should be a good start.

**======= UPDATE =======**

Here's also an example code to see how it could work.
Click **Run code snippet** to see it working.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Quote = props => {
  return <section>
    <blockquote>
      {JSON.stringify(props.quote)}
    </blockquote>
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>Get Quote</button>
  </section>
}

const App = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  const getQuotes = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data && res.data.joke) {
          setQuotes(res.data.joke);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getQuotes();
  }, []);

  return loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <Quote quote={quotes} onClick={getQuotes} />
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
body {
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
   background: white;
   border-radius: 6px;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  font-size: 21px;
}

button {
border-radius: 4px;
background: blue;
color: white;
border: none;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 12px;
font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  max-width: 80px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you codingwithmanny, just tested it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Codingwithmanny beat me to it.

Put the axios call in it's own function, and passdown the function to the button component.

Quote.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Buttons from "../buttons/Buttons";
import axios from "axios";

const Quote = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState("");

  const fetchQuotes = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        setQuotes(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("new quote requested");
  }, [quotes]);

  return (
    <div className="quote-text">
      <i className="fas fa-quote-left" />
      <span id="quote"> {quotes.joke}</span>
      <Buttons quotes={quotes} getNewQuote={fetchQuotes} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quote;
```

Buttons.js

```
import React from "react";

const Buttons = ({ quotes, getNewQuote }) => {
  const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quotes.joke}`;
  //   console.log(twitterUrl);

  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      <button
        onClick={() => window.open(twitterUrl, "_blank")}
        className="twitter-button"
        id="twitter"
        tittle="Tweet This!"
      >
        <i className="fab fa-twitter" />
      </button>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={getNewQuote}>
        New Quote
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-generator-heufm

Answer (score 0):

You Should call New Qoute API on button click.

you button Component

```
import React from "react";

const Buttons = ({ quotes, getNewQuote }) => {
  const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quotes.joke}`;
  //   console.log(twitterUrl);

  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      <button
        onClick={() => window.open(twitterUrl, "_blank")}
        className="twitter-button"
        id="twitter"
        tittle="Tweet This!"
      >
        <i className="fab fa-twitter" />
      </button>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={getNewQuote}>
        New Quote
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Your Qoute component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Buttons from "../buttons/Buttons";
import axios from "axios";

const Quote = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        setQuotes(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const getNewQuote = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        setQuotes(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  return (
    <div className="quote-text">
      <i className="fas fa-quote-left" />
      <span id="quote"> {quotes.joke}</span>
      <Buttons quotes={quotes} getNewQuote={getNewQuote}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

In the `Quote.js` create `getNewQuote` function and call that function inside the `useEffect`.

Then, pass the `getNewQuote` function to the `Button` component and on `New Quote` button `onClick` set `getNewQuote`.

Here is your upgraded sandbox -> [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-generator-t9rel?file=/src/components/quote/Quote.js)

Quote.js

```js
const Quote = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    getNewQuote();
  }, []);

  const getNewQuote = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website/api?format=json")
      .then(res => {
        setQuotes(res.data);
        // console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="quote-text">
      <i className="fas fa-quote-left" />
      <span id="quote"> {quotes.joke}</span>
      <Buttons getNewQuote={getNewQuote} quotes={quotes} /> // here you pass the getNewQuote function to the Buttons component
    </div>
  );
};
```

Buttons.js

```js
const Buttons = ({ quotes, getNewQuote }) => {
  const twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${quotes.joke}`;
  //   console.log(twitterUrl);

  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      <button
        onClick={() => window.open(twitterUrl, "_blank")}
        className="twitter-button"
        id="twitter"
        tittle="Tweet This!"
      >
        <i className="fab fa-twitter" />
      </button>
      <button id="new-quote" onClick={getNewQuote}> // here onClick you call the getNewQuote function
        New Quote
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```